# onclick attribute in tag <a> doesnt work correctly

Tags: php, html, onclick

I have a menu which get its items from database.
I want to get the menu id of clicked menu in following for each:

```
public function gen_menu($menuItems, $pId = 0)
{
    $menu       = '';
    $ulStart    = 0;
    $base_url   = base_url();
    $uri        = $this->uri->segment(1);
    foreach($menuItems as $row)
    {
        if($row->parent_id==$pId)
        {
            if($ulStart==0) { $menu .= "<UL>"; $ulStart++; }
                $url = $row->item_url;
                stripos($url,$base_url)===0 || $url==""?$base_url = base_url():$base_url="";
                {
                    if($row->external==1){
                        $menu .= '<LI><a href="'.$row->custom_url.'" title="'.$row->alt_title.'">'.$row->item_title.'</a>'.$this->gen_menu($menuItems, $row->item_id).'</LI>';
                    }
                    else{
                        $class = ($uri==$row->custom_url)?"class='selected'":"";
                        $menu .= '<LI '.$class.'><a href="'.site_url($row->custom_url).'/'.$row->item_id.'" title="'.$row->alt_title.'" onclick="'.$this->get_id($row->item_id).'">'.$row->item_title.'</a>'.$this->gen_menu($menuItems, $row->item_id).'</LI>';
                    }
                }
        }

    }
    if($ulStart!=0) { $menu .= "</UL>"; }
    return $menu;
}`
```

When I am using onclick in  it returns the last id of table always.

Comment: PHP is a server side language. Do you mean when the browser navigates to this script?

Comment: Can you give a dump of the $menu when it's done? It would make it easier to try to help you.

Comment: the returend $menu is a styled menu with their sub menus. the only thing i need, how to use onclick in tag <a href="'.site_url($row->custom _url).'"...... when i use onclick it returns the last from foreach

Comment: I don't see an `onclick` attribute in your `A`.

Comment: oh sorry i just removed it.... here it is

Comment: the onclick works but always return the last id of table no matter which menu is clicked...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$menu .= '<LI '.$class.'><a href="'.site_url($row->custom_url).'/'.$row->item_id.'" title="'.$row->alt_title.'" onclick="javascript:get_id('.$row->item_id.');">'.$row->item_title.'</a>'.$this->gen_menu($menuItems, $row->item_id).'</LI>';
```

You had `$row->item_id` inside the quoted string, so it wasn't expanded. You should have gotten a javascript error from that.

UPDATE:

The problem you're having is that you're confusing server-side and client-side actions. The code in this PHP script all runs on the server when it's creating the page to send to the user. If you're setting a session variable in the loop, the variable will contain the value from the last iteration. Putting PHP code inside `onclick` doesn't run it when the user clicks, it runs it when the server is composing the `onclick` attribute to put in the HTML that gets sent to the browser.

If you want to do something on the server when the user clicks, you need to put a Javascript function in the `onclick` attribute, and that function should use AJAX to call another PHP script.

Comment: thanks... i just edit the code in post. as i said onclick is working but it always return the last item_id of table menu, no matter which menu is clicked.

Comment: Please post the `get_id()` method.

Comment: function get_id($id=0)
    {
  $this->session->set_userdata('menu_id',$id);
    }        $id is always smoething like 338, the last id of table

Comment: You're putting the return value of that function into the `onclick` attribute, which is supposed to contain Javascript statements.

Comment: Everything in PHP runs on the server when it's creating the page, not while the user interacts with it. You need to use AJAX if you want to run server code in response to user actions.

Comment: I just added more details to my answer.

Comment: wow! thanks. i got the problem!let me try something as u said!